# Energy conservation in projection of a charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, energy-conservation

The question reads, "A positive point charge of mass m is projected with a velocity inside the tunnel as shown. The tunnel has been made inside a uniformly charged non conducting sphere. Find the minimum velocity with which the point charge should be projected such that it can it reach the opposite end of the tunnel."

[image]

The solutions all treat it as a positively charged sphere and therefore arrive at an expression as the answer. But since it hasn't been specified that it's not a negatively charged sphere, couldn't the answer be 0, if it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if the sphere is negatively charged the answer would be zero as the ball is attracted towards the center of the sphere. By the conservation of energy when the ball reaches the other end of the tunnel its velocity would be zero. So it will perform a periodic motion inside the tunnel.

Comment: So without it being specified, the question's incorrect, right?

Comment: You can write the answer like if the sphere is positively charged then this if negative then zero.